# LU decomposition of banded matrix with partial pivoting

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, gaussian-elimination

Disclaimer: I'm rusty as can be in this department.

I'm looking into how to implement a banded matrix LU decomposition with partial pivoting ($PA = LU$). So to start with I implemented regular matrix LU decomposition with partial pivot (code based on C example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition), and I fed it the following initial (banded) matrix:

$$
A^{(0)} = \begin{bmatrix}
5 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\
35 & 64 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\\\
0 & 40 & 22 & 9 & 0 \\\\
 0 & 0 & 18 & 85 & 7 \\\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 19
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So the half band width is 1, and I was hoping that the pivoting would keep the non-zeroes within a half band width of 2. But alas, this does not seem to be the case. See below what unfolds in working through the complete LU decomposition (note that matrix A iterations below contains L + U - the identity matrix, so the intermediate stages in the algorithm implementation):

$$
A^{(1)} = \begin{bmatrix}
35 & 64 & 4 & 0 & 0\\\\
0.142857 & -1.142857 & -0.571429 & 0 & 0\\\\
0 & 40 & 22 & 9 & 0\\\\
0 & 0 & 18 & 85 & 7\\\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 19\\\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Above: row 0 got swapped with row 1.
$$
A^{(2)} = \begin{bmatrix}
35 & 64 & 4 & 0 & 0\\\\
0 & 40 & 22 & 9 & 0\\\\
0.142857 & -0.028571 & 0.057143 & 0.257143 & 0\\\\
0 & 0 & 18 & 85 & 7\\\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 19\\\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Above: row 1 got swapped with row 2.
$$
A^{(3)} = \begin{bmatrix}
35 & 64 & 4 & 0 & 0\\\\
0 & 40 & 22 & 9 & 0\\\\
0 & 0 & 18 & 85 & 7\\\\
0.142857 & -0.028571 & 0.003175 & -0.012698 & -0.022222\\\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 19\\\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Above: row 2 got swapped with row 3.
$$
A^{(4)} = \begin{bmatrix}
35 & 64 & 4 & 0 & 0\\\\
0 & 40 & 22 & 9 & 0\\\\
0 & 0 & 18 & 85 & 7\\\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 19\\\\
0.142857 & -0.028571 & 0.003175 & -0.001587 & 0.007937\\\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Above: final result: row 3 got swapped with row 4.

So the original row 0 got all the way pushed down to row 4, and you see the matrix is now not neatly banded anymore unfortunately.

My question is: am I overlooking something here? The result seems to be correct, if I extract L and U matrices from this, and multiply them, I get back the permutation of $A^{(0)}$.

I've seen a few articles hint that the propagation of non-zeroes is expected to be limited to a half band width that is double of the original half band width, see e.g. https://sep.stanford.edu/data/media/public/oldreports/sep20/20_11.pdf. But the example LU decomposition above seems to contradict this, and a row can propagate as far as it likes. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you're not. I was also struggling around this question, as I was trying to implement a banded LU factorization with partial pivoting by myself.
As a matter of fact, partial pivoting expands the bandwidth, but it's possible to make statements only on the bandwidth of the upper triangular part - this becomes equal to $p + q$, being $p$ the lower and $q$ the upper bandwidth, respectively.

Citing Golub and Van Loan (Chapter 4.3.3, emphasis mine):

> Thus, pivoting destroys band structure in the sense that *U* becomes "wider" than *A*'s upper triangle, while **nothing at all can be said about the bandwidth of *L***. However, since the *j*th column of *L* is a permutation of the *j*th Gauss vector *$\alpha_j$*, it follows that *L* has at most *p* + 1 nonzero elements per column.

*Golub, Gene H.; Van Loan, Charles F.*, Matrix computations., Johns Hopkins Studies in the Mathematical Sciences. Baltimore, MD: The Johns Hopkins University Press (ISBN 978-1-4214-0794-4/hbk; 978-1-4214-0859-0/ebook). xxi, 756 p. (2013). [ZBL1268.65037](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1268.65037).

Comment: Nice find on a reference text on this, good to have some confirmation that I was on the right track. Unfortunate that the article I found seems to be erroneous with regard to band width limits.